# Gerar pdf com Javascript ou AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Alguém conhece uma forma de gerar pdf de uma página via javascript sem o uso de biblioteca ou no maximo com uso do angular JS ?

Comment: Creio não ser possível utilizando somente Javascript ou Angular, mas talvez você possa considerar a possibilidade de usar jsPDF -> http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: na verdade estou considerando o pdf.js biblioteca da mozilla.

Estou realmente não querendo usar, mais pelo jeito terei. . .

Comment: Interessante também :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conheço dois, um deles converte Markdown para PDF, o outro usa um esquema de sintaxe parecido com o FPDF.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit

https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf

Fiz alguns testes com o jsPDF e pdfkit, são bem parecidos no uso e funcionam à contento, mas ainda não testei com geração de muitas páginas.

Comment: muito bom, esse do alanshaw não conhecia. Vou tentar com ele algo. Apesar de ter resolvido já via server, mas para projetos futuros é interessante termos soluções.

Comment: fiz uma geração simples de recibos, sendo que do server somente vem o json dos dados e o desenho do pdf é feito no cliente, ficou muito rápido